# Vue router dissapears only in a production server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I don't know why, but vue stops working, in the html doesn't appear the router-view and it appears like a comment:

[image: e]

I have the standard code with webpack, and always works, but now now.

```
import router from './router/index'
new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    store,
    mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],
    components: {
      TopMenuComponent,
      EventItemComponent,
      GoTopComponent,
    },
    i18n
  }).$mount('#app')
```

**router**

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    // AUTH ROUTES //
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: LoginPageComponent
    },
...
```

The curiosity is that in the local machine it works fine, but when I put exactly the same code in another server, doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The JS console is blank, no errors, no warnings

Comment: Does it give a 404 page?

Comment: @Tuna nope, the page loads, removes <div id="app">, and put the comment <!-- -->

Comment: which command do you use to run it locally? and in the other server?

Comment: @niccord Just yarn dev and yarn build. In local machine works with both, and not in the server

Comment: I am not very familiar with `yarn` but are you sure you have installed all dependencies on the server? like `npm install` (maybe it's just `yarn`)

Comment: yes, is the same, that works fine because in local machine works all good :S

Comment: @MarcGarcia Are you sure you don't have `vue-router` in `dev-dependencies`?

Comment: @AdamOrlov sure, is in "dependencies"

Comment: @MarcGarcia are you able to share your code? There will be a lot of guessing otherwise...